# Combine duplicates and total in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Not the greatest at Excel.....but basically my data looks like:

```
   A           B             C              D  
Part Number  Qty           Amount      TOTAL $ 
0020056      1.00        1,300.00    $1,300.00
```

I need to remove the duplicates in Column A, have a new total in Column B, total C, and total D.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Try to look into the remove duplicates function in excel.

Comment: yeah, I did that but it won't total the other columns that way.

Comment: tried the pivot table and I cant get what I need out of it.

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more data and an expected outcome, since the way I read this doesn't really make sense.  How do you know which duplicates to remove (Qty or amount could be different in the different duplicates which would give you different answers in your totals).  If you just have a row at the bottom that sums all the previous rows it would update if you removed duplacates.

Comment: ahhh, just figured it out. I'll ask something again some time soon. Bookmarked.

Comment: @richstinksatexcel You can post your solution as an answer. It might be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: I'm having this problem and would appreciate you posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the subtotal function in Excel

For your particular scenario set these values.

At each change in -> set that to column A
Use function -> set to Sum (should be sum already)
Add subtotal to -> put a tick next to all the columns you want to sum. By the sounds of it, it is all the other columns

Click Ok